Indentify this movie where a camper driver die by drugs overdose
I saw some time ago a movie where a camper driver goes on holiday with his daughter (10 years old or somewhat), they find a country abandoned home.
The driver then use drugs and dies by overdose, the daughter think he's sleeping and play around the house for some days meeting the strange people of the place before she realize her dad is died.
Anyone ever seen this film and remember its title? I want to see it again.
Language of the movie was english and I watched it 3 years ago.
That's all the details I can give, I tried to search a whole afternoon for the movie on internet, I have bad memory for people so I can't say hair colors or other details about characters, but I remember the story and that the film had a very surreal atmosphere.

Could be Tideland: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0410764/

possible, I try to watch it. If that movie fits the description why not posting an answer? If that is the movie I accept it, but any movie fitting the description should be upvoted(I think, even if most similiar questions and answers are downvoted here)

Ok, I wrote an answer.

This sounds a lot like the plot of Tideland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tideland_(film)

Tideland centers on an abandoned child, Jeliza-Rose, and her solitary adventures during one summer in rural Texas while staying at a rundown farmhouse called What Rocks, and focuses on the increasingly dark, imaginative fantasy life the girl creates with the aid of dismembered Barbie doll heads that she often wears on her fingertips
After her mother chokes to death, Jeliza-Rose and her father, Noah, flee to Noah's mother's home, a remote Texas farmhouse. Noah fears that with all the drugs in their house he will lose Jeliza-Rose and be sent to prison, so he attempts to set it alight before they leave, although Jeliza-Rose manages to stop him.
Noah dies from a heroin overdose. For much of the rest of the film, Noah's corpse remains seated upright in a living room chair with sunglasses covering his eyes. As her father slowly begins to decompose, Jeliza-Rose doesn't readily acknowledge his death because she has grown accustomed to him being unconscious for long periods at a time. Instead, she retreats deeper and deeper into her own mind, exploring the tall grass around the farmhouse, relying on her doll heads for friendship as an unconscious way of keeping herself from feeling too lonely and afraid.

Here is the trailer: 



yes thanks that's the correct movie :)
